# SharePoint 2007 - Get Central Admin URL ID (guid)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am looking to get the GUID of the Central Administration page in SharePoint but not sure how I can get it, any help would be appreciated.

I need to be able to get this dynamically using the API / Object Model

Thanks

Phill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication

SPAdministrationWebApplication adminWebApp = (SPAdministrationWebApplication)SPWebApplication.Lookup(myUri);

SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spadministrationwebapplication.aspx

Comment: Thank you John, I will check it out once I have fixed a bug I am working on (D'oh!)